# How do I make a Discord Bot Command where only a certain role can use said command. (On Node.js)

Tags: node.js, encoding, scripting, bots, discord

What I mean is where only a certain Role (Owner) can execute the command that has been made. This has to be able to be done on the language node.js.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Discord.js you can use `message.guild.owner`.

In order to check if a message send by a certain user is allowed, you can do

```
if(message.guild.owner === message.member)
{
    /* Code here */
}
```